# Writing Java RDDs into a Hive schema from Apache Spark

Tags: java, hive, apache-spark, rdd

We have a Java Apache Spark application that we submit to YARN. We want to load all the processed data into a Hive schema. From Apache Spark documentation it looks like writing the RDDs into an HDFS file and loading that into Hive looks like the solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Spark SQL can interoperate with Hive. (See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables).) It can create Hive tables. I don't know if it can put RDD data into Hive tables. It would certainly be a useful thing if it could!

Comment: So I serialized my JavaRDD into a JavaRDD json's. Saved that file in hdfs and loaded it into a hive table.